# what are restrictions on using parse in xml-twig to parse xml string

Tags: perl, xml-twig

I am trying to use $twig->parse($xmlstring) to add id attribute to all xml elements in string. Each string is an element of an array that looks something like:

```
<classes name="Test::Class">
  <public_methods>
    <members const="no" kind="function" name="RegisterDefinition" volatile="no">
      <parameters declaration_name="name" type="std::string"/>
      <parameters declaration_name="description" type="std::string"/>
    </members>
  </public_methods>
</classes>
```

In script I use foreach loop to get each element and create id attribute.

```
foreach my $str (@newonly) {
   $twig->parse( $str );
}
```

I create twig object and TwigHandler that calls routine and it only works if I use parsefile and specify xml file. Does not work if I use parse to parse part of xml file that is element of an array.
Routine I am using is:

```
my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
 TwigHandlers => {
   '_all_' => \&add_id,
 },
);


sub add_id 
 { my($twig, $element)= @_;
   $element->set_id($id++);
   $twig->purge;
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Does not work"? What is the expected result?

Comment: Expected to see new attribute in each element "id = 1", etc. Works if I use parsefile on xml file but not if I use parse on a string. Guess my question is if string I am trying to parse valid, as indicated in Test::Class string example.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aTwig):

> parse ( $source)
>
> The $source parameter should either be a string containing the whole XML document, or it should be an open IO::Handle (aka a filehandle).

Answer (score 0):

I am confused about the use of `$twig->purge` at the end of the handler. When you do this, you lose all of the structure you've just built. I think you do create the id's, but you loose them when you purge the twig.

You should probably remove the call to `purge` and add a handler on `classes`, that would use the twig for whatever you need to use it for, and then purge it, once you're done with it.

Comment: Removed call to purge, but discovered that my problem is that id attribute is being added to all xml elements in string that is an element of an array, however, not written back to element in array. Array is used again later in script, but string is in original state before id attribute is added.

Comment: of course, the twig is _not_ the string, it is built from the string. You would need to set the array element to the serialization of the XML, ie `$array[$i]= $twig->sprint`, or in your case `foreach my $str (@newonly) { $str= $t->parse( $str)->sprint; }` (in a `foreach` loop the "cursor" is an alias to the original variable, see the discussion of Foreach loops in `perldoc perlsyn`